# How to correctly use purgeServerSideCache to refresh the Ag-Grid in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, ag-grid-react

I tried `this.gridApi.purgeServerSideCache([]);` in my method to refresh the Ag-grid in react but still this does not render a refresh. So even if values are added to the grid even after calling the `save()` method which calls the `purgeCache()` method.

```
  save() {

  /* Some code saving to the server database, values which  
   will have to be updated in the grid. */

   this.purgeCache.bind(this);

   }

   purgeCache() {
   this.gridApi.purgeServerSideCache([]);
   }
```

I followed this example stated on the official site for Ag Grid
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-server-side-model-grouping/#purging-groups

I need the Ag Grid to refresh every time the `save()` method is called. Currently the refresh doesn't happen and no error message is shown to show if something has gone wrong. It is like the `this.gridApi.purgeServerSideCache([]);` is completely ignored and no refresh is done.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to ditch the `purgeCache()`. This might not be best practice but it worked for me as a workaround to refresh the ag-grid state once `save()` method is called. I actually decided to spilt the grid method.

Where I can refresh the set grid information in `initGrid()`

```
onGridReady = (params) => {
this.gridParams = params;
this.gridApis = params.api;  // Set on the first on grid ready call
this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

this.initGrid();

}

initGrid = () => {
    var dataSource = {
      rowCount: null,
      getRows: async function (params) {
        var props = params.context.componentParent.props;
        var skip = params.startRow;
        var take = params.endRow - params.startRow;
        var response = await props.dispatch(actions.getShopList(skip, take));
        var rowsThisPage = response.retailshops.items;
        var lastRow = response.retailshops.itemsCount;
        params.successCallback(rowsThisPage, lastRow);
    }
  };
  this.gridApis.setDatasource(dataSource);
  this.gridApis.refreshCells(this.gridParams); // Using Ag Grid refreshcells method
  this.gridApis.sizeColumnsToFit();
  }

  save() {

  /* Some code saving to the server database, values which  
     will have to be updated in the grid. */

   this.initGrid();

  }
```

Then I was able to call the `initGrid()` method after I have updated server information, to ensure that the new updated information can show in the grid. This will be helpful if your sole purpose was to refresh the grid with updated information.